# How to Disable button when redirecting to another asp.net pages?

Tags: asp.net

I have two(2) buttons in Approve.aspx which is the bttnVerify and bttnApprove. The thing is that  during page load bttnApprove.visible= false and when the user click the bttnVerify it will redirect to another page. Redirect page code below.

```
     Captcha1.ValidateCaptcha(txtCaptcha.Text.Trim())
    If Captcha1.UserValidated Then
        lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green
        Response.Redirect("~/Accounts/AccountsApproval/" & Session("IDs"))

    Else
        lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
        lblMessage.Text = "InValid"
    End If
```

From the code above, when Its captcha is validated I wanted to disable particular button in that page which is bttnApprove and  bttnVerify.visible = true.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    If Captcha1.UserValidated Then
        lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green
        Response.Redirect("~/Accounts/AccountsApproval/" & Session("IDs"))
        bttnApprove.Enable = false
    Else
        lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
        lblMessage.Text = "InValid"
        bttnVerify.Enable = false
    End If
```

you can enable or disable a button by setting property `Button.Enable`.

Comment: this buttons are from other pages

Comment: are you using master pages

Answer (score 0):

use `bttnApprove.Enable = false;`

Comment: I tried it, the thing is that how to disable button from content pages to another content pages.